# How is the induced electric field due to a changing magnetic field divergence free?

Tags: electromagnetic-induction

How can we show that the divergence of the induced electric field is zero

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mathematically, the divergence of a curl is always zero. Induced electric fields are represented by Faraday's Law of induction from Maxwell's Equations, which says the curl of the electric field goes like the (negative) time derivative of the magnetic field.

The divergence of a curl is a little like finding 
$\vec A \cdot (\vec A \times \vec B)=0 $. 
Since $\vec A \times \vec B $ is perpendicular to $\vec A$, the dot product comes out to zero.

Physically, induced electric fields go in loops, and the divergence asks how many sources (beginnings or ends) of electric field lines there are. Since a loop doesn't have a beginning or end, the answer is zero.

Edit:
You might try looking at the electric field in terms of the potentials.  Here's an outline of something you might try.

$\vec E=-\nabla \phi-\frac{d \vec A}{dt}$

The induced electric field is just going to be

$\vec E=-\frac{d \vec A}{dt}$

$\nabla \cdot \vec A=C$

Where C depends on the gauge, but is time invariant.

So,

$\nabla \cdot \frac{d \vec A}{dt}=\frac{d \nabla \cdot \vec A}{dt}=\frac{dC}{dt}=0$

Comment: Yes I get that the divergence of a curl is equal to zero.

Comment: Yes I get that the divergence of a curl is always equal to zero ie divergence(curl E)=0 where curl E = -del B/del t .But in Griffiths he writes that this induced field itself is divergence free ie divergence E=0. Starting from the only information we have that is curl E =-del B/del t.  How can we mathematically say that divergence E = 0.     PS : I just joined so I am not acquainted with the mathematical symbols on this  site. forgive me for that

Comment: You might try looking at the electric field in terms of the potentials.